# Nodejs React run function before render

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm new to Nodejs and React and having problems trying to run a function before a render. I have set up a page to allow for an admin to view all users registered on the website, and it works fine if there are users. However, when a user tries to access this ViewUsers page, the authorization middleware sends a response saying they are not allowed to view the page. The users is then set to empty, which gives problems when the user.map() function runs in the render. The notfound page is supposed to run in the checkAuth() function before the render runs. I get this error

```
TypeError: users.map is not a function
```

This is my code for the view users page.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import AdminServices from "../Services/AdminServices";
import "././ViewUsers.css"

export default class ViewUsers extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.retrieveUsers = this.retrieveUsers.bind(this);
        this.checkAuth = this.checkAuth.bind(this);

        this.state = {
            users: []
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.retrieveUsers();
    }

    retrieveUsers() {
        AdminServices.getAllUsers()
            .then(response => {
                this.setState({
                    users: response.data
                });
                console.log(response.data);
                console.log('DATA RECEIVED')
                this.checkAuth();
            })
            .catch(e => {
                console.log('ERROR')
                console.log(e); 
            });
    }

    checkAuth() {
        if (this.state.users.length === 0) {
            window.location = '/notfound'
        }
    }

    render () {
        const { users } = this.state;

        return (
            <div className="viewusers">
                <h1>All users</h1>
                <div className="viewusers-list">
                    {users.map((user) => {
                        return (
                        <React.Fragment>
                            <p> <b>Name</b> : {user.username} </p>
                            <p> <b>Email</b> : {user.email} </p>
                            <p> <b>Website role</b> : {user.websiteRole} </p>
                            <hr />
                        </React.Fragment>
                        )
                    })}
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure `users` is an array?

Comment: What does your route look like in node? Typically the auth middleware would be part of the route and passes the next() function. That way you Auth, if found then move to the next function in the route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try something like this.

Create a `ViewUsers` component that takes `users` as a prop.

```
const ViewUsers = (users) => {
           <div className="viewusers">
                <h1>All users</h1>
                <div className="viewusers-list">
                    {users.map((user) => {
                        return (
                        <React.Fragment>
                            <p> <b>Name</b> : {user.username} </p>
                            <p> <b>Email</b> : {user.email} </p>
                            <p> <b>Website role</b> : {user.websiteRole} </p>
                            <hr />
                        </React.Fragment>
                        )
                    })}
                </div>
            </div>
}
```

Only load the `ViewUsers` component when `users` are defined.

```
render () {
        const { users } = this.state;
        if (users) {
            return ViewUsers(users)
        }
        return <div>Loading users...</div>
    }
```